# commerce-email-order-items as a view doesn't show up when it's sent by anonymous

Tags: views, commerce, emails

When I use this,

```
<?php function bobr_commerce_email_order_items($variables) {
  // Get order wrapper
  .$order_wrapper = $variables['commerce_order_wrapper'];
  // Get rendered view
  .returnviews_embed_view('clone_of_shopping_cart_summary', 'default', $order_wrapper->getIdentifier());
}?>
```

I can have email table as a view, so I can theme it. It works great, but only when I'm logged in as an Administrator.

When I do an order as an anonymous, the view table doesn't show up in email. How can I fix it?